# For loops in 2d array AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, loops, for-loop

I am trying to fill a 2D array in AngularJS but I am stuck in the logic part. Basically I am trying to fill in something like that with data retrieved from the database:

```
[
[BizTech, marks, recommendations],
[IT, marks, recommendations]
]
```

The number of modules depends on how many records in the database. How exactly do I loop through the 2D array to insert the records ?

The code I have right now looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i == 10; i++) {
     $scope.resultsArray[0][0].push($scope.moduleCode)
     $scope.resultsArray[0][1].push($scope.marks)
     $scope.resultsArray[0][2].push($scope.moduleRecommendation)
                               }
```

EDIT:

I have changed to one for loop, but when I do a console.log($scope.resultsArray, "results"), there is an error saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.
```

What went wrong here ?

Comment: It looks like you only need one loop because the inner arrays are always the same size (is there a reason you're using arrays for the entries? plain objects would be more appropriate). But your example code doesn't make sense right now because `$scope.moduleCode`, etc. are going to have the same value for the entire loop.

Comment: Also you can't use the array's length in the loop if you will be adding some more elements inside the loop.

Comment: @mojarras What limit must I set for the loop if I cannot use the length of the array ?

Comment: Well, you should always set a fixed value as the loop counter so that your loop can start and finish correctly. If you use a variable that will be changing it's value from within the loop, that's when you get infinite loop errors. That fixed value should be the answer of the question: "How many times do I want my loop to run?" and that of course will be determined by the logic you are trying to accomplish.